# How to center 3 subfigures one under the other

Tags: floats

In fact, I want to have a figure containing 3 subfigures where each figure has to be in a separate line 
here is the code that I have used but it illustrates them in one line.

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.360]{fig1}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.360]{fig2}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.360]{fig3}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: You can replace `\hfill` by an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

You can achiveve this only using `\centering` also inside the `subfigure`s. There are some slight differences in terms of vertical spacing compared to StefanH's answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
        \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}    
  \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\centering` inside `subfigure` hasn't any function: images has size of `subfigure` environment ...

Comment: That is true, I actually did not pay attention, I merely reused the code from the previous answer. However, it still centers for other sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in a table. (I removed the star from `figure` since it now becomes a high figure environment instead of a wide).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}    
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the benefits of using a `tabular` as compared to aranging the `subfigures` without a `tabular`?

Comment: @leandriis There are many ways to do this, so I think it is a matter of taste. I find it often easy to get things side-by-side or on top of each other with help of tables.